# 600 different sql request same time in java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem and I could not figure it out, and I have no idea to search that with which key words.

I have mysql database, and a java program. In my database, there is a table like "doors" and in doors table there are 3 column like "door_id, door_name, door_active". My tables like :

```
door_id    door_name    door_active
   1       frontdoor          1
   2       backdoor           0
   3       sidedoor           1
   4       garagedoor         1
```

So, in this table if door_active ='1', doors listing. If I need one door name in java, mysql, my code and sql like that :

```
Statement st1 = baglantiAc();
ResultSet res1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT door_name FROM doors WHERE door_active='1' AND door_id = '1'");
while (res1.next())
{
jMenuItem1.setText(res1.getString("door_name"));
}
```

But I have **600 datas** in one request.

My question is, how can I make a code like 600 **active** doors in one request, for menu items.

Note : I know my sql like **ResultSet res1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT door_id, door_name FROM doors WHERE door_active='1'");** but what about java code ? For each menu items to each results ?

For example my code will be like this ? But it is not work :

```
Statement st1 = baglantiAc();
ResultSet res1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT door_id, door_name FROM doors WHERE door_active='1'");
while (res1.next())
{

if(res1.getString("door_id").equals('1'))
{
 jMenuItem1.setText(res1.getString("door_name"));
}


if(res1.getString("door_id").equals('2'))
{
 jMenuItem2.setText(res1.getString("door_name"));
}
}
```

this code is not work but also not giving any error.

Best Regards,

Comment: Well `WHERE door_active='1' AND door_id = '1'` happens to match just 1 door.  You already have a while loop to traverse your ResultSet, so if you create a query that's less restrictive (as explained by juergen d) your loop will be executed as many times as there are hits in your resultset.

Comment: Have you tried: `res1.getInt("door_id") == 1)`

Comment: And by not working you mean your menuitems have no door names, right?

Comment: @juergend yes, you are right.

Comment: Problem solved from @juergend . And the code like : 

    Statement st1 = baglantiAc();
    ResultSet res1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT door_id, door_name FROM doors WHERE door_active='1'");
    while (res1.next())
    {
    if(res1.getInt("door_id") == 1)
    {
    jMenuItem1.setText(res1.getString("door_name"));    
    }
    if(res1.getInt("door_id") == 2)
    {
    jMenuItem2.setText(res1.getString("door_name"));    
    }
    
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either fetch all and filter out in java

```
SELECT door_name 
FROM doors 
WHERE door_active='1'
```

or if the data is sequential you can do

```
SELECT door_name 
FROM doors 
WHERE door_active='1' 
AND door_id between 1 and 600
```

or you could use the `in` clause

```
SELECT door_name 
FROM doors 
WHERE door_active='1' 
AND door_id in (1, 3, ..., 600)
```

And in your java code replace

```
if(res1.getString("door_id").equals('1'))
```

with

```
if(res1.getInt("door_id") == 1)
```

Comment: There is no problem in sql, I can figure it, but in java, how can I list each door name for each menu item. I found just one request.

Comment: You want one MenuItem per door? You'll need to create some collection of menuitems. Maybe I just don't understand the question.

Comment: @HaroldWren You need to do more in your `while (res1.next())` loop - in each iteration read the ID and name and add them to e.g. a map of ID->name, or create a new menu item and add it to the master menu, or whatever you need for your framework.

Comment: I think you need to give more detail in your question about that.